# target="_blank" links inside iframe

Tags: iframe

I load a page from another domain with iFrame which has target="_blank" links. When I click, the url is opened in a new page as usual. How can I avoid those links to be opened in new windows? I want those links to be opened inside the iframe.

Comment: That's how they're supposed to work. If you own the page that's being loaded in the iframe, just remove the _blank.

Comment: No, I don't own the page loaded in the iframe, that's why I need another solutions.

Comment: That makes it more complicated.  There are some methods of doing what you want but only if the iframe points to the same domain as the page it is in.

Answer (score 3):

The only real solution would be to change `target="_blank"` to `target="_self"`. Or remove the target attribute completely and let the default action occur (which is `_self`).

This question might be a re-post of this: [Force any HREF in an IFrame to use its parent as the target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225245/force-any-href-in-an-iframe-to-use-its-parent-as-the-target), but some of those techniques might be useful to you.

But if the page is on a domain you have no control over, you can't really do anything.

Comment: I have no control/access to the page loaded. So I can't play with the codes at backend. I had tried those techniques but none of them helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's a browser-level function, so you can't affect its behavior using html.

You could create a proxy that filters all data you're displaying (you could wipe out all target="_blank"), but that defeats the simplicity of just using an iframe.  Sorry.

Comment: I guess using a proxy to load the page will dramatically slow down the server on high traffic. It would be better if it is possible on the user-side. I tried CORS but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking for solution in 2023. Add sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" to iframe (without "allow-top-navigation"). In cases where you dont need the user to leave the site this will do the trick.

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="https://example.com"/>
```

You will get the error in the console if someone press external link :

```
Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin '....' from frame with URL 'https://example.com'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.
```